# Shoutem - How does it work for custom backend/integrations?

Tags: shoutem

Interested to learn more about the product. The frontend seems very straightforward. What I'm curious about is how much "backend" services your tools supply? For features that you run the backend for, is there API access?

This is the use case I'm trying to understand. If we were to sign up as an agency, would we be able to 1) create an app with your system 2) add custom features/native modules/etc and 3) connect that app to a custom dashboard which we run ourselves

Answer (score 1):

From the backend services, Shoutem has its own **Cloud Storage** to manage your data in the app and **Automated app publishing** tool for publishing your app to both stores. You can [customize Shoutem Cloud](http://shoutem.github.io/docs/cloud/introduction) with your data models.

To answer other questions:

1. Yes, everyone can create their app on Shoutem.
2. Shoutem is just an architecture on how to create React Native apps. Apps are divided into smaller building blocks, called extensions. This architecture enables developers to reuse extensions in multiple apps which leads to more efficient app development process. You can build your [custom extension](http://shoutem.github.io/docs/extensions/my-first-extension/introduction) and that extension can use any feature from React Native,
   including [native functionalities](http://shoutem.github.io/docs/extensions/tutorials/using-native-api). We made sure not to restrict you on how you can use React Native.
3. Our extensions are by default connected with Shoutem CMS. Since they are [open sourced](https://github.com/shoutem/extensions), you can customize them to use your own backend instead. For your own extensions, you chose which dashboard they are going to use.

Extensions are built from 2 parts: **app** part and **server** part. App part represents application logic, while **server** part allows the customization of Shoutem Server including Dashboard and CMS. For Dashboard, you can write [Settings pages](http://shoutem.github.io/docs/extensions/tutorials/writing-settings-page) which can be hosted anywhere, including on your own backend.

All the underlying concepts are explained on Shoutem's Developer portal: [shoutem.github.io](http://shoutem.github.io/)